# Chrome throwing error with onload and load functions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, onload, google-chrome-devtools

This is working, however my strict QA say there can be no console errors.

I've writing an iframe to the DOM, and setting up a .onload event;

```
var configureSDK = function () {
        alert('lets configure');
    }

    var init = function (config) {
        // pass configurables to global var
        settings = config;
        setupSDK(document);

        function setupSDK(d) {
            // setup iframe
            sdkportal = d.createElement('IFRAME');
            sdkportal.setAttribute('src', '//www.webtekkers.com');
            sdkportal.setAttribute('width', '100%');
            d.body.appendChild(sdkportal);
            sdkportal.onload(configureSDK());
        }
    }
```

Like I said it works, BUT Chrome is showing;

Uncaught TypeError: Property 'onload' of object # is not a function

Now I know, I should really be setting up individual events AddEventListener|attachEvent('load|onload') for the different browsers, but that's more work.

Is this just Chrome being WRONG or am I?

*Please no jQuery alternatives*

Thanks Will

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message, although hard to understand, is exactly right.  `onload` is a property, and its value is `undefined` until you assign something to it. Usually it will be assigned a *reference to a function*.

You probably mean to set the `onload` property to the `configureSDK()` function reference:

```
sdkportal.onload = configureSDK;
```

Or as a function call (if you had more work to do in the `onlaod`):

```
sdkportal.onload = function() {
  configureSDK();
};
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, that's done it.  I always forget that it's a property not a method...